# Is calling getResources().getString(<string_id>, params) inside loop degrades performance

Tags: android, performance

I wanted to know if calling getResources().getString(, params) inside  a loop degrades the performance.

I have the below string defined in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="score">The score is %d</string>
```

and inside the loop I'm accessing it like this

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.score, score));
```

I don't how `getResources().getString()` works internally, so not sure if its a good idea to call this in a long loop.

If its a heavy operation I could use `String.format()` inside java class but then I'll loose the related localization defined for this string.

Please suggest if this is a bad practice and there is any better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to answer a question like this is to try it out and measure the results. I made these strings:

```
<string name="plain">Hello world</string>
<string name="variable">Hello %1$s</string>
```

And then I made an app that loaded each of them once, and then each of them a thousand times, and measured the number of nanoseconds that took. I ran it on a pretty old tablet running a pretty old version of Android, and got these results:

```
getString(R.string.plain);
```

```
getString(R.string.variable, "StackOverflow");
```

> ```
> I/System.out(31427): Loading one plain string took 91,552 nanos
> I/System.out(31427): Loading one variable string took 183,106 nanos
> I/System.out(31427): Loading a thousand plain strings took 38,055,421 nanos
> I/System.out(31427): Loading a thousand plain strings took 67,352,294 nanos
> ```

So, it takes 0.18 milliseconds to load a string with format arguments a single time, and 67.35 milliseconds to do the exact same thing a thousand times. My conclusion is that loading the same resource repeatedly has *some* optimization, but not an incredible amount (it took about one third as long as we'd expect with no optimization).

I also measured the same test using `String.format("Hello %s", "StackOverflow")`, and got these results:

```
String.format("Hello %s", "StackOverflow");
```

> ```
> I/System.out(31849): Formatting one variable string took 152,588 nanos
> I/System.out(31849): Formatting a thousand variable strings took 22,613,526 nanos
> ```

So doing the formatting directly in java is marginally faster for a single attempt, but significantly faster when repeated.

Finally, a test that bridges the gap. I use `getString()` without format arguments, and then `String.format()` to do the formatting. This means I only access the resources framework a single time, but still get the benefits of internationalization etc. Here are my results

```
String template = getString(R.string.variable);
String.format(template, "StackOverflow");
```

> ```
> I/System.out(32094): Formatting one variable string took 213,623 nanos
> I/System.out(32094): Formatting a thousand variable strings took 28,015,135 nanos
> ```

Here, a single invocation is the worst performer of them all. This makes sense; we're manually doing all the work we were getting "for free" before. But doing it a thousand times is still a significant win over loading from resources every time.

---

All in all, the question still comes down to what you're doing, how often you're doing it, and what kind of performance you need. Consider that Android draws a frame to the screen approximately every 16 milliseconds... loading a thousand variable strings from resources would cause you to skip 3-4 frames. But if you're only loading a hundred strings, then you wouldn't skip any.

Comment: What an excellent answer. Thank you for this detailed performance analysis. I would go with `getResource().getString()` as I've less than 20 strings in my application.